# Filling Nan Values in Multi-Index Groupby Object

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pivot-table

I'm trying to create a multi-index groupby object that takes email domains and finds the percent change by month. I'm running into issues when an observation is absent for a given month.

**Original Dataframe**

```
tracking_df = tracking_df[['transaction_mm_yy', 'ST_Email_Domain', 'isFraud', 'order_number']]
```

I created a pivot table, resulting in below:

```
tracking_df.pivot_table(index=['transaction_mm_yy', 'ST_Email_Domain'], 
`columns='isFraud', values='order_number', aggfunc='count')`

                   isFraud              1
transaction_mm_yy  ST_Email_Domain
2017-10            GMAIL.COM           31.0
                   HOTMAIL.COM          2.0
                   TSF.COM              9.0
                   MAIL.COM             3.0
                   OUTLOOK.COM        214.0
                   YAHOO.COM           20.0
2017-11            AOL.COM              3.0
                   GMAIL.COM           14.0
                   HOTMAIL.COM          9.0
                   TSF.COM              5.0
                   MAIL.COM             9.0
                   OUTLOOK.COM         14.0
                   YAHOO.COM           62.0
2017-12            AOL.COM             21.0
                   GMAIL.COM          101.0
                   HOTMAIL.COM         13.0
                   TSF.COM              8.0
                   MAIL.COM            11.0
                   OUTLOOK.COM         14.0
                   YAHOO.COM           41.0
2018-01            AOL.COM              7.0
                   GMAIL.COM           88.0
                   HOTMAIL.COM          8.0
                   TSF.COM             21.0
                   MAIL.COM             2.0
                   OUTLOOK.COM          8.0
                   YAHOO.COM           13.0
```

As you can see below, AOL.COM shows observations for every month except 2017-10. I'd like AOL.COM to show an observation with a NaN count or zero count.

**Attempt**

Following the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html), I tried using *reindex* by defining the date range and then recreating the index.

```
date_index2 = pd.date_range(start_date_range, periods=4, freq='m')
date_index2.strftime('%Y-%m').tolist()

tracking_df.reindex(date_index2, fill_value=0)
```

However, I get an error:

```
ValueError: cannot include dtype 'M' in a buffer
```

I can guess that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the way

```
s.unstack().stack(dropna=False).fillna(0)
Out[774]: 
transaction_mm_yy  ST_Email_Domain
2017-10            AOL.COM              0.0
                   GMAIL.COM           31.0
                   HOTMAIL.COM          2.0
                   MAIL.COM             3.0
                   OUTLOOK.COM        214.0
                   TSF.COM              9.0
                   YAHOO.COM           20.0
2017-11            AOL.COM              3.0
                   GMAIL.COM           14.0
                   HOTMAIL.COM          9.0
                   MAIL.COM             9.0
                   OUTLOOK.COM         14.0
                   TSF.COM              5.0
                   YAHOO.COM           62.0
dtype: float64
```

Another way is to using category data at the beginning

```
tracking_df.ST_Email_Domain=tracking_df.ST_Email_Domain.astype('category')

tracking_df.pivot_table(index=['transaction_mm_yy', 'ST_Email_Domain'], 
`columns='isFraud', values='order_number', aggfunc='count')
```

Comment: would you explain the .astype('category') in the second block of code?

Comment: @jonjon hope the link will help https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html

Answer (score 0):

You can `reindex` with `df.index.levels`.  This assumes you assigned your pivot table to `df`

```
df.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product(df.index.levels))

isFraud                  1
2017-10 AOL.COM        NaN
        GMAIL.COM     31.0
        HOTMAIL.COM    2.0
        MAIL.COM       3.0
        OUTLOOK.COM  214.0
        TSF.COM        NaN
        YAHOO.COM     20.0
        vTSF.COM       9.0
2017-11 AOL.COM        3.0
        GMAIL.COM     14.0
        HOTMAIL.COM    9.0
        MAIL.COM       9.0
        OUTLOOK.COM   14.0
        TSF.COM        5.0
        YAHOO.COM     62.0
        vTSF.COM       NaN
2017-12 AOL.COM       21.0
        GMAIL.COM    101.0
        HOTMAIL.COM   13.0
        MAIL.COM      11.0
        OUTLOOK.COM   14.0
        TSF.COM        8.0
        YAHOO.COM     41.0
        vTSF.COM       NaN
2018-01 AOL.COM        7.0
        GMAIL.COM     88.0
        HOTMAIL.COM    8.0
        MAIL.COM       2.0
        OUTLOOK.COM    8.0
        TSF.COM       21.0
        YAHOO.COM     13.0
        vTSF.COM       NaN
```